# What is the effect of adding '$' dollar sign infront of event in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

What is the effect of adding '$' dollar sign infront of event in Angular?

```
onModelUpdated($event: any) {
    console.log($event);
  }
```

vs

```
onModelUpdated(event: any) {
    console.log(event);
  }
```

Comment: @Vega both are valid, and `$event` in the class will not generate an error.

Comment: @ulmas, right, because I have stricter rules activated

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`$` prefix in variable names has no any kind of an effect. A `$` dollar sign in JavaScript (and TypeScript by extension) is a valid identifier to use as part of a variable name, it carries no syntactical meaning. It can be used in the beginning, middle or end of a variable/function name.

Specifically when it comes to `$event` and its use in Angular, it is more of a convention carried over from the days of AngularJS. In AngularJS, [internal variables exposed by the framework were prefixed with a `$`](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_events.asp).

That is why sometimes you see `event` and other times `$event`.

There was [a proposal to get rid of it](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8425), but nothing happened.

So it is more of a question of style and conventions, and it is up to the personal/project preferences to come up with a convention about whether to use `$event` or `event`.

Answer (score 4):

Using `$event` as an argument when invoking the event handler (while binding events on templates) allows you to fetch the event data. It's like some kind of reserve word in Angular. If you use the event (without `$`) you'll get an error.

If your handler needs this data, that's the way to get access.

Comment: I don't seem to get an error when I just use event but I get "undefined". Just thought I would add that here.

Comment: From my experience, the code could compile without problems, because Javascript/Angular wise, it doesnt really matter, but the IDE will yell at you for not using the "$event" reserved word.

Answer (score 3):

Just to be crystal clear, `$event` is the name of the event argument [as defined in the Angular framework](https://angular.io/guide/event-binding).

> Parent directives listen for the event by binding to this property and accessing the data through the `$event` object.

The dollar sign is part of the name, hence it has to be reported as such. Once more, it is not a convention that you might follow or not, it is a name already given by the internal framework to an object and you have to call it by its name, in order to access it.

Notice that you have to use `$event` in the **html template**, while in your class you can redefine the argument of the function as you wish.
Example from [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs#configuring-the-parents-template): the *event payload* is *necessarily* written as `$event` in the html template `src/app/item-output/item-output.component.html`

```
<app-item-output (newItemEvent)="addItem($event)"></app-item-output>
```

but then you're free to call the argument in your class (e.g `src/app/app.component.ts` here) as most appropriate (in this example `newItem: string`)

```
addItem(newItem: string) {
  this.items.push(newItem);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, its interesting however in skimming the linked documentation, although I see that $event is used with the dollar sign, i did not see any text in the article that discussed the necessity of the $