# Difference between event and $event

Tags: javascript, typescript, naming-conventions

I am using Angular, and I am trying to understand the differences between `event` and `$event`. I know this is just a naming convention, but I am not sure when to use it.

Is there a rule to this? Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Yes and no. For instance, they are referring to the dollar sign being connected to Angular and that I am not supposed to use it within my code. At the same time `HostListener` examples all contain `$event` in user code.

Comment: Also see [What is the effect of adding '$' dollar sign infront of event in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59806843/924299)

Comment: That's a much better explanation. Weird I haven't found that thread. Thanks for the links!