# Why are events written as $event in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, variable-names, event-binding

I'm an Angular beginner, and during the course of learning Angular, various tutorials and websites have used naming conventions that declare events as **$event** as shown in below snippet:

```
@HostListener('dragover', ['$event'])
  onDragOver($event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    this.hovered.emit(true);
  }
```

I've also seen similar conventions for naming observables where observables are named as **myObservable$**

A similar question: [What is the meaning of $ in a variable name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7484210/what-is-the-meaning-of-in-a-variable-name) actually even mentions that it is *against convention* to start a variable name with the $ sign

My question is, does the dollar symbol bear any additional significance in Angular? Does it affect event binding in any way or are these just accepted conventions?
Appreciate even if someone can just point me in the right direction with a significant link to documentation

Comment: Check this answer will help You:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37671700/angular2-style-guide-property-with-dollar-sign

Comment: Does this answer your question? [angular2 style guide - property with dollar sign?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37671700/angular2-style-guide-property-with-dollar-sign)

Comment: Yes these links were helpful, thanks so much So pretty much the same thing applied to events too right? That its just a naming convention, nothing more?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the effect of adding '$' dollar sign infront of event in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59806643/what-is-the-effect-of-adding-dollar-sign-infront-of-event-in-angular)